# App Indexing with Ampersand in Deep Link not working

Tags: android, deep-linking

We are trying to implement [Google's App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app) feature. We've added the deep links to our website with the rel-alternate tag in the following format:

```
android-app://id.of.the.app/scheme/?screen=Product&product=123456
```

Now we get content mismatch crawling errors. If I use the QR code for testing from [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/test) everything works fine. But if I open a crawling error, click on "Open App Page" and use the adb command for testing I can see that everything starting from the ampersand doesn't get passed to the app and therefore my product data cannot be loaded. I suspect that's how the crawler checks the content of the app and that's why we get Content Mismatch Errors.

Also if I use the "Fetch as Google" from the Search Console it looks like everything from the ampersand gets cut off.

I checked on eBay as it is working with their app and that's the link they are using:

```
android-app://com.ebay.mobile/ebay/link/?nav=item.view&amp;id=221559043026&amp;referrer=http%3A%2F%2Frover.ebay.com%2Froverns%2F1%2F711-13271-9788-0%3Fmpcl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ebay.com%252Fitm%252FRoxy-Fairness-Backpack-Womens-Red-RPM6-%252F221559043026%253Fpt%253DLH_DefaultDomain_0
```

They have encoded the ampersand with `&amp;` but if I do that and test it with the "Fetch as Google" function it doesn't work either.

These users seem to have the same issue, but they didn't share a solution (if they found one):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/5r7KdetlECY/enYknTVkYU4J
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/lswyXKlS-Ik

I'm thankful for any ideas.

**Update 1**

That's how I'm interpreting the deep link inside the Android app:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme();
if (scheme.equals("scheme")) {
    String screen = data.getQueryParameter("screen");
    if (screen.equals("Product")) {
        String product = data.getQueryParameter("product");
        // Open Product and give it product number as intent data
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Here's the relevant part of our Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="id.of.the.app.StartActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_title"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="scheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: How do you get the content after the ampersand ?

Comment: I updated my question and added some code on how the deeplink is processed in the android app

Comment: I'm not getting your issue and I'm using a web page and adb command directly. Could you share how you get the 'crawling error'?

Comment: In the Google Search Console I see a lot of 'content mismatch' errors. Google says the content of our web page doesn't match the content of the app page. I suspect that Google uses the adb command to compare the content. The product isn't loaded due to the ampersand issue and thus Google thinks the contents wouldn't match. At least that's my theory. What drives me crazy is, that it works with the eBay app.

Comment: The url you're using with adb is `android-app://id.of.the.app/scheme/?screen=Product&product=123456`? What is the url you get from Google Search? How do you test the ebay app?

Comment: No :) That's the URL that's implemented on our website on the link-Tag. To test it I use the adb command Google suggests on the crawling error: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d scheme://?screen=Product&product=123456 id.of.the.app`. If I use the second method to test it using [this](http://applinktest.appspot.com/app-link.html?utm_source=wmx-ui&utm_campaign=android-app%3A%2F%2Fid.of.the.app%2F&url=android-app%3A%2F%2Fid.of.the.app%2Fscheme%2F%3Fscreen%3DProduct%26product%3D123456) link it works as expected and I'm on the correct page on the app.

Comment: I know the eBay app works, because the deep linking works :) If you use the Google search on Android and search for an article the search result directly opens in the ebay app. It seems like they don't get any crawling errors because it wouldn't work then.

Comment: Yeah, I know the adb shell command. I was just wondering if it is exactly the schema you're providing, since I've no issue with that. I've just added a \ just before the &amp; since it's a special char and it's not interpreted by the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 3**
I'm still trying to understand if it's is possible to avoid a change to the manifest and resubmit the app. With the AndroidManifest you have published, have you tried to change just the rel-alternate tag to include a host (event if it's not included inside the manifest)? For example have you tried with `android-app://id.of.the.app/scheme/fakehost/?screen=Product&product=123456` where fakehost is a string? I guess that the syntax of the tag must be `android-app://{package_name}/{scheme}/{host_path}`so it's neccessary to have an host in the web site (but probably not on the app).

---

**Update 2**
After you published the Manifest, I guess you're missing the mandatory '**host**' in the data tag of your Intent-Filter.

Get this as reference:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="link"/>
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="link/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and the meta in html should be (android-app://package-name/scheme/host)

```
<html>
<head>   
<link rel="alternate"
      href="android-app://it.test.testdeeplink/myapp/link/?p1=1&p2=2" />
...
</head>
```

You probably need to update your app, since your Manifest will have to be fixed.

---

First, thanks for all clarifications. I guess there is some confusion about deep link (the feature you're implementing) and [Chrome Intent](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) (the link that you provided as comment). So, I decided to implement a small project that you can download by my [dropbox folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13066693/TestDeepLink.zip). The project is very simple and has a single activity that prints a line for every *parameter* received by Intent data (of course if you launch the app by the app launcher you won't see anything). The Activity supports two intent-filter schemas (my-android-app and http), and at the end of MainActivity.java you can find (as comment)

1. A line to test deep linking against adb and the first schema
2. A line to test deep linking against adb and the second schema
3. A simple html page to test the deep link using a browser - the last two href are Intent properly managed by Chrome.

Since I don't have access to your code, and I cannot see if there is any issue, I guess this is the best way to help you and to get my answer accepted :)

Comment: I'd love to award you for your effort, but it doesn't solve my problem. I edited my question to try to make it more clear. We're implementing the App Indexing feature (see link in answer). It links the content of your website to content within your app. If that happened and a user searches on the smartphone the search result isn't opened in the browser anymore. It directly opens your app. For that to work Google needs to know how they can reach the content within the app. That's done via the rel-Tag. But Google keeps complaining that the contents wouldn't match and I have no idea why...

Comment: I didn't test any of it yet. Problem is that changes on our website take about a week until they are deployed. Even if they are as little as changing a simple link-Tag. We tried to manipulate the tag with jQuery but these changes do not get picked up by the Google Crawler. Because your answer looks like the most promising, I'm going to award you the bounty. I'll accept your answer if it was the solution later on.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt - sorry for being curious: have you checked if the proposed solution work as expected?

Comment: I'm not sure... We discovered that our deeplinks are working for some page, but for most pages it's still not working. We will just give it some time and see what happens. The "fetch as Google" feature never returns the correct page. I suspect this to be the problem, but I can't figure out why it isn't rendering the correct page...

Comment: Today we discovered that the crawling errors have halfed. It seems to be working now and only needs time until the other sites have been crawled by Google. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, happy to know that my help was useful.

Answer (score 0):

App indexing with query params in the `Uri` works fine for me. Please check if you followed all steps correctly:

- Declare the scheme for the `id.of.the.app.StartActivity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

  ```
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
              <data android:scheme="my_custom_scheme"/>
          </intent-filter>
  ```
- Parse deeplink

Let's assume we have following deeplink `my_custom_scheme://test_authority/product_screen/?product=123456&test_param=0000&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=appindexing`

```
    public void parseDeeplikUrl(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
           // fallback: open home screen
        }
        String autority = uri.getAuthority();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String query = uri.getQuery();

        // authority = "test_authority"
        // path = "products_screen"
        // query = "product=123456&test_param=0000&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=appindexing"
    }
```

- Test app indexing from command line:

  ```
  adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "my_custom_scheme://test_authority/product_screen/?product=123456&test_param=0000&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=appindexing" -e android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME android-app://com.google.appcrawler/https/www.google.com id.of.the.app'
  ```

Using this `adb` command we simulate `GoogleBot` call.

- Go to `"Fetch as Google"` in `Search console` and check if `GoogleBot` works fine too and renders correct application screen.

  ```
  android-app://id.of.the.app/my_custom_scheme/test_authority/product_screen/?product=123456&test_param=0000&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=appindexing
  ```

**P.S.**: Sometimes `GoogleBot` isn't rendering screens correctly. I got few empty screens with correct the deeplinks. In that case try to execute the same deeplinks again. It worked for me.